# Merging two data together in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation, dataframe

I am trying to concatenate data  together in pandas but it doesn't appear to be working out well for me.

I have some data that I wanted to convert to a numeric and I was able to do this. I then want to have it rejoin the data set.

Here is what the original data looks like:

```
 CallDate            Agent          Group     Direction
0  2015-09-01         Adam          Billing    Inbound
1  2015-09-01         Nathaniel     Billing    Outbound
2  2015-09-01         Jessica       Claims     Inbound
3  2015-09-01         Tom           Billing    Outbound
4  2015-09-01         Jane          CCS        Inbound
```

Here is my code to convert the group to a numeric

```
data['Group']=data['Group'].astype(str)
data.Group=data['Group'].apply(lambda x:len(x))
```

This worked and gave me what I was looking for
    0     1
    1     1
    2    13
    3     1
    4     6

I then try to merge this back to the group (basically I want to know what each name/number correspond to)

```
y=pd.concat([data,data.Group], ignore_index=True)
y [:5]
```

But the results are the same as the original database

Is there something obvious I am missing or an easier work around that I am not thinking of.

Comment: post the other data set also

Comment: As WoodChopper said, your code does not fit your 'original data', it accesses `AssignedWorkGroup` but that's not in the data you show. Also include the code that prints those numbers (0 1 1 etc) for you, and maybe the full output you expect from your code.

Comment: @sgvd
sorry forgot to clean up labels a bit

Comment: @ user3120266 Do you want to concatenate `Billing` + `len(Billing)`?

Comment: @WoodChopper actually no, it would be a separate column. So group would still exist, but then a separate column with the number

Comment: Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.concat()` is to concatenate two `DataFrame`. I think you are trying to concatenate two columns in `a DataFrame`.

```
data
Out[42]: 
     CallDate      Agent    Group Direction
0  2015-09-01       Adam  Billing   Inbound
1  2015-09-01  Nathaniel  Billing  Outbound
2  2015-09-01    Jessica   Claims   Inbound
3  2015-09-01        Tom  Billing  Outbound
4  2015-09-01       Jane      CCS   Inbound

data.Group = data.Group + data.Group.apply(lambda x:" / "+str(len(x)))

data
Out[44]: 
     CallDate      Agent        Group Direction
0  2015-09-01       Adam  Billing / 7   Inbound
1  2015-09-01  Nathaniel  Billing / 7  Outbound
2  2015-09-01    Jessica   Claims / 6   Inbound
3  2015-09-01        Tom  Billing / 7  Outbound
4  2015-09-01       Jane      CCS / 3   Inbound
```

You can find more details in pandas concat [API documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-objects)

Update for new column,

```
data['Group_1'] = data.Group + data.Group.apply(lambda x:" / "+str(len(x)))

data
Out[56]: 
     CallDate      Agent    Group Direction      Group_1
0  2015-09-01       Adam  Billing   Inbound  Billing / 7
1  2015-09-01  Nathaniel  Billing  Outbound  Billing / 7
2  2015-09-01    Jessica   Claims   Inbound   Claims / 6
3  2015-09-01        Tom  Billing  Outbound  Billing / 7
4  2015-09-01       Jane      CCS   Inbound      CCS / 3
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `cat` function to concatenate two series in `pandas` check the [Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html#pandas.Series.str.cat) here for the `cat` function .

also you can get the number of characters in any word easily by using the `len` function `df.Group.str.len()`

```
df['Group'] = df.Group.str.cat(df.Group.str.len().astype(str), sep=' => ')
df
Out[42]:
CallDate    Agent          Group         Direction
2015-09-01  Adam          Billing => 7   Inbound
2015-09-01  Nathaniel     Billing => 7   Outbound
2015-09-01  Jessica       Claims => 6    Inbound
2015-09-01  Tom           Billing => 7   Outbound
2015-09-01  Jane          CCS => 3       Inbound
```

Comment: Nice to see list comprehension :)

Comment: I removed it by the way , this looks pretty much better :)